# Question about aggregate functions with GROUP BY SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have for example 10-15 fields in table different types (varchar, nvarchar, int, float, datetime e.t.c.) and i need to make GROUP BY, so. What function of aggregate i have to use on all of this fields? MAX or something else? Is it important?

```
SELECT
    intFacilityRTOPID,
    MAX(ObjectSystem_r_Equipment) ObjectSystem_r_Equipment,
    MAX(ObjectBuilding_r_Equipment) ObjectBuilding_r_Equipment,
    MAX(intenum_EquipmentTypeID) intenum_EquipmentTypeID,
    MAX(correctionDate) correctionDate
FROM [RTOPv4History].[dbo].[FacilityRTOP]
WHERE cast(correctionDate as bigint) <= @correctionDate
GROUP BY intFacilityRTOPID
```

Comment: Entirely depends on your desired results! For each `intFacilityRTOPID` for example which of the possible `ObjectSystem_r_Equipment` values do you want returned? The largest, the smallest, one from a specific row?

Comment: Only you know your data well enough to know if it is important or not. min and max will return the same if you only have "one value" in a column for a given `intFacilityRTOPID`. If there are more than distinct value it will of course return different values. Does that matter or not? You tell me.

Comment: Yeah, my bad. I udnerstood my mistake, thx.

Comment: But, if it doesn't matter for me, which value i want bcz they all the same, what function i have to use to aggregate this fields?

Comment: If it does not matter then use whatever you like. It does not matter.

Comment: Well it doesn't matter if only Max, Min or Avg are being considered... but Count(), Sum(), Var() and stDev() generate different values

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you might not understand what `Group By` does.    Group By establishes a set of "bins" or "buckets", defined by the values of the group By columns or expressions, that will control the output of the query.  i.e., the result rows of the query will be constrained to unique combinations of the values defined by the group by columns and/or expressions, and all data in each row is constrained from the subset of the original table that mach that "definition"..

Any columns in the eoutput that are not exactly the same as one of the group by column/expressions must use one of the many aggregate functions to specify and/or calculate what value to generate for that column.  The value generated will be taken from actual table column values from only those rows in the original table that match the group By column/expression.  So if you use `MAX()`, you get the biggest of that subset of the values, if you use `AVG()` you get the average, etc...

If you really don't want to do any aggregation, then consider just using the `Distinct` keyword....

```
 SELECT Distinct intFacilityRTOPID, 
     ObjectSystem_r_Equipment ObjectSystem_r_Equipment,
     ObjectBuilding_r_Equipment ObjectBuilding_r_Equipment, 
     intenum_EquipmentTypeID intenum_EquipmentTypeID,
     correctionDate correctionDate 
 FROM [RTOPv4History].[dbo].[FacilityRTOP] 
 WHERE cast(correctionDate as bigint) <= @correctionDate
```

Comment: Yeap, but if i have 1000 the same values in column- what function i have to use? Is it important? I can take any of them, first, last, min, max- they are all the same.

Comment: As someone else commented, it depends on whagt you want. if the values are all the same than `Max()`, `Min()`, `Avg()` will give you the same value, `Sum()` will add them up, `STDEV()` will give you the standard deviation, etc. What function of the set of values do you want ?

Comment: If you just want the value which is in all the rows, then use Min() or Max().  But if you rally don't want to do any aggregation at all, then consider just using the `Distinct` keyword.

Answer (score 0):

If the complementary column are all equal, you may want to

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT DISTINCT(intFacilityRTOPID) 
  FROM [RTOPv4History].[dbo].[FacilityRTOP]
  WHERE cast(correctionDate as bigint) <= @correctionDate
) a CROSS JOIN (
  SELECT TOP(1) 
    ObjectSystem_r_Equipment,
    ObjectBuilding_r_Equipment,
    intenum_EquipmentTypeID,
    correctionDate
  FROM [RTOPv4History].[dbo].[FacilityRTOP]
  WHERE cast(correctionDate as bigint) <= @correctionDate
) b
```

which *could* perform better depending on the size of the table. Caveat: I haven't tried if this works and I am writing by memory :-)